# How to use pip install to install lazypredict (Python package) using a MacOS Ventura 13.1, using Spyder

Tags: python, macos, spyder

These are my codes:

```
import pip

pip install lazycredit
```

And, I get this error:

```
File "<ipython-input-8-bda080a7b858>", line 1
pip install lazycredit
    ^

SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pip install` is a commandline command, not a python command. Based on your question I would strongly suggest you look into beginner tutorials such as [this one](https://realpython.com/what-is-pip/) to better understand how to manage python packages.